# Localization in french text not displaying properly: é to &#233; instead of é

Tags: c#

I'm working with the localization file. I get the following text string in english "name="Approved" not being translated correctly in french, the issue is with the "é".

"A Approuvé." in my resx file get displayed in my view as "A Approuv & # 233";

And I have the following value for my french translation: lan.fr-CA.resx:

```
<data name="Approved" xml:space="preserve">
<value>A approuvé</value>
```

My chtml file is :

```
{ dataField: "FormattedApprovedDate", calculateSortValue: 
"ApprovedDate", dataType: "date", caption: 
'@(Language.Translate(Language.Keys.Approved, ViewBag))'},
```

A screen shot is included. Any idea...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvTrA.png)

Comment: you'll have to see about safely using @Html.Raw

Comment: See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references  You need to use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) and System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string) encode and decode special characters.

Comment: Is that Language.Translate maybe converting that é into an entity representation, which then gets encoded?